# Django default settings 1.6 BASE_DIR acting up

Tags: django, django-settings

In the new template for settings django 1.6 generates the following code:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

However this has never worked for me and I keep changing it to

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Is their code wrong or am I missing something? The idea of this BASE_DIR is to avoid hardcoding dir names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is to get two directories above your settings directory.

Your code `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is the same as `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

You probably changed where your *settings.py* resides and for that you must change its path.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't move them, I was assuming this had to point to a different place, stupid question it seems.. Thanks